# Debug asp.net 5 application with specific domain

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to run my ASP.NET 5 (beta7) application in Visual Studio 2015 on a specific domain, mydomain.com for example. How could it be achieved?

Hosting the published version would lose the Visual Studio debuging. Built in IISExpress launch profile do net let domain address change, just port number of localhost address.

**EDIT:** I've solved the problem with self-host, Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener, but is there a way to do that with Windows IIS 8.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Publish your app to the file system and set up an IIS site as described in the [documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html). You can use a custom domain if you [override](https://www.mojoportal.com/adding-a-host-name-to-the-hosts-file-for-local-testing) routing in the `etc/hosts` file.
2. In Visual Studio, go to `Debug -> Attach to process`
3. Check `Show processes from all users`
4. Find process called `w3wp.exe` and attach the debugger to it
5. Now your breakpoints will be hit as if hosted in IIS Express...

Comment: But it seems a bit harder than the usual approach of using F5.

Comment: It is. But does your application always require to be hosted in the full IIS in order to be debugged? In my experience IIS express does the job in 80% of all cases.

Comment: The problem with IIS express is the domain name restriction.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had to attach to the correct **dnx.exe** process **not the w3wp.exe**. 
I found the correct dnx process by looking at the username it was running under. It was the app pool identity that I assigned the site to in IIS.

**Update (2016-09-14):**
With the release of .NET Core 1.0, I now must attach to a process that is named the same as my project. Eg. if my project is name *TestWebApp* then the process I attach to is named *TestWebApp.exe*.